# how to compile an ANT project that depends on a GRADLE-BUILT project?

Tags: java, gradle, ant

I've got a web application made of several project: Back-end is gradle compiled and depends on a entities-project also gradle-built. How ever, my webservice project is ant compiled but also depends on the gradle compiled entities-project.

For the moment, I'm not able to compile de entities-project from the webservice ant compilation. How can I add the dependence in my scripts/build.xml to be compiled with gradle from my ant webservice project?

- This is how I create the jar in my **build-dependencies**.xml:

  ```
      <!--  By default the dependant projects are compiled as a result of a Check Out   -->
  <target name="co.dependency" depends="tag.or.head" unless="use.local">
      <subant target="dist" 
              antfile="build.xml" 
                  buildpath="${tmp.dir}/${dependent.git.project.repo}.${dependent.git.project.tag}/scripts"/>
      <copy todir="${lib.dir}" file="${tmp.dir}/${dependent.git.project.repo}.${dependent.git.project.tag}/dist/${dependent.project.name}.jar" />
      <copy todir="${lib.dir}" file="${tmp.dir}/${dependent.git.project.repo}.${dependent.git.project.tag}/dist/license-loader.jar" />
  </target>
  ```
- And this is the **error message** I get:

  ```
  dist:
       [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/myuser/projects/entities-project/dist
       [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/myuser/projects/entities-project/dist
   [trycatch] Caught exception: The following error occurred while executing this line:
   [trycatch] /home/myuser/projects/WebService/scripts/build-dependencies.xml:91: Warning: Could not find file /home/muyser/projects/entities-project/dist/entities-project.jar to copy.
  ```

  BUILD FAILED
  /home/myuser/projects/WebService/scripts/build.xml:49: No message

Comment: Which one do you want o build first, gradle type project or ant type project ?

Comment: While Gradle has full Ant support, the reverse isn't true. You'll have to use Ant's `exec` task to launch Gradle as you would from the command line.

Comment: I want to build the ant project first, so that this project builds the gradle one by itself.